# Opening a url in browser using c#, chrome does not allow to open new window

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome, .net-core, openurl

On a button click I'm opening a url in default web browser. It is working fine but when I try to manually open a new window(normal or incognito) of the same browser from start menu it is not allowing. I'm facing this issue in chrome only.I'm using below code to open web browser url.

```
 private void OpenUrl(string url)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = url,
                UseShellExecute = true
            };
            Process.Start(ps);
        }
```

Please help me if there is any other and better way to open url in c# so I can avoid chrome issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "not allowing" - **exactly** what error do you see?

Comment: Try it  Process.Start(Uri.ToString())

Comment: @Max This gave me error "'The system cannot find the file specified.'
"

Comment: @Dai I don't see any error but it is not opening any new window also. If I open as admin It is opening it.

Comment: Process.Start("https://stackoverflow.com/")  Its work for me, make sure you fully indicate the url path. " If I open as admin It is opening it" - Then try adding StartInfo.Arguments = "/user:Administrator"

Comment: I'm using dotnet core, it works well with dotnet framework but not with dotnet core that is reason it is not working.
Did you try to open more windows and it allowed ?

Comment: Any suggestion on this? I'm stuck with issue since long and no luck?